# Batch file - timestamp when closed

Tags: file, batch-file, timestamp

I have written a batch file that puts a timestamp to a file, and then does this every minute that passes by.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto :main

:main
    echo !time:~0,5%! -start>> time.txt
    :loop
    findstr>nul /rc:"\<!time:~0,5%!\>" time.txt
    if !errorlevel!==0 (
        goto :loop
    )else (
        echo !time:~0,5%!>> time.txt
        echo 
        goto :loop
    )
goto :eof
```

but how do i get it to make a timestamp when i close the program?

the output looks like this

```
15:23 -start
15:24
15:25
```

Comment: Your code is just an endless loop.  So when you say, make a time stamp when you close the program, do you mean forcefully closing the program with your mouse by clicking the X?

Comment: yes thats what i mean

Comment: If you close the batch-file, which is what I assume must be the 'program', then how do you expect a closed batch file to perform a task? The only way you could do that would be to run the batch file from another process, and have a mechanism in that process determine when that batch file no longer running. This could then potentially trigger, if it has such functionality, a write of the time to the same output file, in the same format, _(if it is not still locked as open by the batch file)_.